# How do I switch Node projects in WSL?

Tags: node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After I start a project with `npm init`, how do I: a) switch to another project, and b) come back to this one and continue it later? Does this require a project manager of some kind?

I've tried to find nodejs project managers, though I get referred to pm2 and forever, but pm2 seems super complicated, and I'm not even sure it does what I need it to, and forever runs a specific script for. . . well. . . forever, which s also not what I want.

To start a project, I use: `npm init`

I can create a project, of course, but I have no idea how to close the project temporarily and/or switch back to it later and continue.

Comment: `npm init` creates a `package.json` file in the current directory.  Is that what you mean by a "project"?  Not sure what you mean by "close the project".  Creating a file doesn't somehow "open" a project.  I'm a little confused.  Are you using an IDE or something?

Comment: No, apparently `npm init` initializes a project, in which it holds everything in a `package.json` file. So, I'm guessing that I just change directories to work with another project? Do I have to close the JSON file I'm working on before switching, or do I have to tell node that I'm now working on something else (i.e., load the other JSON file) or something? Or is it automatic that node closes the current `package.json` when I change directories?

Comment: nope.  it's really simple.  just change dirs and npm init your next project.  you can close package.json files in your editor if you want or not.

Comment: `package.json` is just a file, like a `.txt` file. `npm init` [create a package.json file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init)

Comment: This is awesome, guys! Thanks, so much for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

It's really not so complicated.  You can create two projects as long as they're in different directories like this.

```
user@machine:~$ mkdir src
user@machine:~$ cd src
user@machine:~/src$ mkdir project1
user@machine:~/src$ cd project1
user@machine:~/src/project1$ npm init
(...follow the prompts here)
user@machine:~/src/project1$ cd ..
user@machine:~/src$ mkdir project2
user@machine:~/src$ cd project2
user@machine:~/src/project2$ npm init
(...follow the prompts here)
user@machine:~/src/project2$ cd ..
```

This will leave you with `~/src/project1/package.json` and `~/src/project2/package.json`

The package.json files are just text files.  Neither node nor npm keep the package.json file open.

But, you can open the package.json file in your favourite editor to make changes.  Save the changes when you are done.  Closing the file again in your editor is up to you, depending on whether or not you want to make further changes.

Comment: Nice. Now it all makes sense! Thanks!